# Microsoft graph unable to get required data from .Net core application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Net core application and I am trying to do some operation based groups and users. Below code I have

```
public  async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphApiClient()
        {

            var credentials = new ClientCredential(_authenticationConfig.ClientId, _authenticationConfig.ClientSecret);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid");
            var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);
            var accessToken = token.AccessToken;

            var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage
                .Headers
                .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }));
          
            return graphServiceClient;
        }
```

I am trying to query as below

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = await _myRepository.GetGraphApiClient();
 var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

This is throwing exception.

```
  "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
  "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
```

I have set required permission in my azure ad app also. I have attached screenshot.
Also I have granted Admin consent also. Can someone help me what I am missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Azure ad app permissions]

Comment: Thanks. May I know why should I change to application permission? Oh correct there is no Me even I was thinking same. Can I try something like List all groups?

Comment: If you want to use the `/me` endpoint, you should make sure to authenticate using a username & password, instead of clientId/clientSecret.

Comment: Hi  Nsevens, Please confirm me If I have to use app or delegated permissions?

Comment: Could you please share the requestid and timestamp for the failed request?

Comment: Use `var user = await graphClient.Users["userid"].Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: { "error": { "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", "innerError": { "date": "2021-01-12T12:42:33", "request-id": "d5faea85-933f-4cc7-8987-7e80526ce079", "client-request-id": "d5faea85-933f-4cc7-8987-7e80526ce079" } } }

Comment: Hi Shiva, Can you please confirm me I should use delegate or app permissions? currently I have used app permissions

Comment: Do you want your users to authenticate to you app? or you want to make it a backend script to run?

Comment: No user authentication not required.

Comment: You need to use Application permissions and use `var user = await graphClient.Users["userid/UPN"].Request().GetAsync();`. Use userid/UPN to get the particular user profile

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: What you are using in your code is a daemon-based client credential flow, which does not have a user logged in, so you should grant application permissions to the application and then call the `/users` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs I am able to understand now and I gave app permissions and working fine now. If I have user logged in then which flow I should use? Can some one help me on this

Comment: You can use Auth code grant flow for user login. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: What @Shiva said is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Client Credential Flow you will be getting an App token and the Application will act as a daemon application. So you need to make sure that you use Application permission. Here `/me` doesn't mean anything if there is no user to authenticate right?. So you need to use the code as below to get a particular user details.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["userid/UPN"].Request().GetAsync();
```

You can get all users UPN/userid using the below code.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```